# How do authentication tokens and authorization work in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, authorization

I'm new to reactjs and I've ben trying to understand how the authentication token works to protect routes. In various tutorials people get that token from an api when logging in a user, and then store it along with a "isAuthenticated" variable set to true in localStorage. Then when routing they check if isAuthenticated is true, without any api call to verify the token. Is that safe? I was trying to implement authorization in the same way, by just adding some isAuthorized variable, but can't both of these be tampered with since react works client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course they can. Whatever is on the client is fully controlled by the user. There is no "client-side authorization". Such features (access control to certain functionality on the client) is usually a user experience feature, like why show something to the user that won't work anyway.

All authorization must be done server-side.

This inherently means that it's usually ok to have page structures (views) without data in the client for anybody to see, the point is that data from the backend will be authorized and will only be available to appropriate users.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you